# Mot pour qualifier la sensation que l'on ressent après avoir obtenu la chose que l'on a attendu pendant longtemps

Tags: demande-de-mot

Je recherche un mot pour qualifier cette sensation.
J'ai attendu pendant longtemps une offre d'emploi, et j'ai enfin une réponse positive, par exemple.

C'est une sorte de soulagement, de satisfaction, de détente...

Comment: si la chose correspond à passer d'un état douloureux à un état de liberté on peut parler de "délivrance".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il existe plusieurs mots qui peuvent qualifier - il suffit de faire une recherche dans un dictionnaire des synonymes ...

> **le répit**
>
> **l'apaisement**
>
> **la paix**
>
> **le contentement**

Mais tous reviennent à cet effet de "soulagement" comme vous avez déjà cité.

Comment: Il me semble que je cherche quelque chose de plus fort que du soulagement, mais moins fort qu'une "délivrance". Je me demande si c'est simplement que ma perception du soulagement est faussée par rapport à sa réelle définition.